# how to concatenate multiple Array of Strings into one single String in Scala

Tags: scala

This seems to be a simple question, but I just don't have the idea out of my head. I've done some search with no direct finding.

```
val lines = sc.parallelize(List['its fun to have fun,','but you have to know how.'])
```

All I need to see is a result (in RDD) that shows the  of the entire string.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific on the command please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a `rdd` like the following

```
val lines = sc.parallelize(List("its fun to have fun,","but you have to know how."))
```

Then you would need to `collect` and use `mkString` to make them a string

```
lines.collect().mkString(" ")
```

which would be

```
its fun to have fun, but you have to know how.
```

You can convert it to `rdd` again if you want to see it in `rdd`

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(lines.collect().mkString(" ")))
```

Comment: I guess, you've meant `sc.parallelize(Seq(lines.collect().mkString(" ")))`. If String is parallelized as-is, without wrapping it in another Seq, it results in RDD[Char].

Comment: Thanks @user4637357, yes I definitely forgot the Seq. :)

Comment: @Choix glad to hear that the answer is helpful. If it is helpful then you should upvote and accept :)